# Sklearn train test split

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have loaded in a dataset from UCI (Contraceptive Method Choice Data Set) and need to perform a `sklearn` train/test/split. When I try using:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(contraception_data, contraception_data.target, test_size = 0.5, random_state = 1)
```

I get this error when I run the code, any reasons why:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'target'
```

Comment: check whether the dataframe have the column name traget without target column how can you will seprate the column form the dataset

Answer (score 0):

The dataset in question has 10 columns, the last of which is the target variable (contraceptive method used).

Since there are no column names, the easiest way to select X and y is to use the `iloc` method of dataframes, which selects by index or slices. Here, you can use [:, :-1] to obtain all rows and all columns but the last and [:, -1] for all rows and only the last column.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(contraception_data.iloc[:, :-1], contraception_data.iloc[:, -1], test_size=0.5, random_state=1)
```